# query data right after elasticsearch is ready

Tags: elasticsearch

I wrote my own `QueryParser`, and I would like to query some data to initiate some variable. I could not do it in the Constructor of `QueryParser` but I would like to query the data right after Elasticsearch is started. Is it possible? If possible, how am I supposed to write the code?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, maybe the warmer api can be of help?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-warmers.html

Maybe you can do something with a plugin, in here you have a nice example:
http://jfarrell.github.io

Have a look at the part where the AbstractLifecycleComponent is used.

hope that helps